# My Javascript file won't run because of bigint error

Tags: javascript, npm, solana, metaplex

I am trying to use @metaplex/js to do some NFT minting. Usually my .js files work properly but when I run the file this error comes up.

***bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)***

I don't really get what that means. So, I tried to run npm run rebuild but rebuild is said to be a missing script and I couldn't find a way to install it.

Here is my code:

```
import { Connection, programs} from "@metaplex/js";
import { Loader } from "@solana/web3.js";
const { metadata: {Metadata}} = programs;


const connection = new Connection("devnet");
const tokenPublicKey = 'my_adress';

const run = async() => {
    try{
        const ownedMetadata = await Metadata.Loader(connection,tokenPublicKey)
        console.log(ownedMetadata)
    }
    catch{
        console.log('Failed to fetch')
    }

};

run();
```

If you have any idea, or simply an explanation of what my error means, I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are getting this error because a nested dependency has a compilation step that might not succeed in your platform. [This issue](https://github.com/trufflesuite/ganache/issues/1080#issuecomment-906550239) provides a good explanation.

> [...] This happens because one of our dependencies (bigint-buffer) runs a compilation step on installation and this can step may fail for a couple of reasons. One of the reasons is that your system might not have the build-tools the library is looking for. You can install these build tools on Windows (see https://www.npmjs.com/package/windows-build-tools), but you don't actually need to as it automatically falls back to a pure JS solution instead. Though I agree... that warning is very annoying.

However, this should give you a warning and still allow you to compile your code.

It is worth noting that the current JS SDK from Metaplex is going to be deprecated in favour of the new one: https://github.com/metaplex-foundation/js-next

With the new JS SDK, you can fetch an NFT using the following piece of code.

```
import { Metaplex } from "@metaplex-foundation/js";
import { Connection, clusterApiUrl } from "@solana/web3.js";

const connection = new Connection(clusterApiUrl("mainnet-beta"));
const metaplex = new Metaplex(connection);
const mintAddress = new PublicKey("ATe3DymKZadrUoqAMn7HSpraxE4gB88uo1L9zLGmzJeL");

const nft = await metaplex.nfts().findByMint({ mintAddress });
```

Answer (score 1):

I experienced this issue as well. In my case, it was occurring in an acceptance tests setup using a very simple docker image starting from `node:21.4.0-bookworm-slim`. Notice the `*-slim` part, which means an image with the absolute minimal preinstalled packages.

```
FROM node:21.4.0-bookworm-slim

WORKDIR /code
COPY package* tsconfig.json /code
RUN npm install
```

Of course, running the tests, which happens to use `bigint-buffer`, was displaying the warning. Although nothing was failing, it was a performance concern (maybe...). In any case, I can't sleep with these warnings polluting my terminal.

```bash
$ docker compose exec client npm run test:acceptance

> solana-client@1.0.0 test:acceptance
> rm -rf ./dist/* && tsc && node --test dist/*.test.js

bigint: Failed to load bindings, pure JS will be used (try npm run rebuild?)
✔ reads own balance (53.348432ms)
▶ creates/deletes PDA
  ✔ fails for non-admin user (12.346694ms)
  ✔ fails for insuficient lamports (7.776273ms)
  ...
```

Running `npm run rebuild` as suggested inside the container didn't help. Digging deeper, it turns out that `bigint-buffer` uses native C bindings for performance reasons, but as such it requires certain dependencies to exist on the host to compile the file written in C. In case these dependencies are not there, it will fallback gracefully to JS implementation, which will still work, but will be less performant.

The build is performed by a tool called `node-gyp`. This is not very clear from the `bigint-buffer` perspective, but in `node-gyp` the dependencies are clearly described in their [README](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp?tab=readme-ov-file#on-unix):

- A supported version of `Python`
- `make`
- A proper C/C++ compiler toolchain, like `GCC`

In my Debian setup, all I needed was to install `python3` and `build-essential` (which contains `make` and `gcc`), adding the following to the `Dockerfile` *before* running `npm install` (so the OS dependencies are there when `bigint-buffer` is installed by `npm`):

```
RUN apt update \
    && apt install --assume-yes --no-install-recommends \
        build-essential \
        python3
```

If you are running this locally, of course you can just install the equivalent dependencies directly on your computer. Of course if you are using another distro, MacOS or Windows you'll need different dependencies, but the spirit is same.

And done! Optimized native big numbers are now used and no warning is displayed anymore!